# Optimizing the read of child records of many parents

Tags: mysql, optimization

The main table has a complex query that selects the jobs that are to be displayed on the current workstation.  In addition to the main job record there are a couple of child tables with a few dozen records per parent.  All of this data must be pulled in in order to display the current status of the job.

The child queries are `Select * From Stations Where RecordID in ([list of IDs of the jobs being displayed])`.  The profiler is flagging this as bad.  In digging I realized there wasn't an index on `RecordID` column, I added it--and it didn't help one bit.

How would I go about improving the performance here?  Long ago I tried reading the child records with the parents, that bombed horribly.  I can't imagine doing separate queries for each `RecordID` wouldn't introduce more wait time even if the database was more efficient.

Any other approaches here?

Edit:  While investigating the `temporary tables`I stumbled upon the `Explain` command and now I think the profiler might be flagging it erroneously--when I fed my query into the workbench with an explain it came back with only one line, almost 16,000 rows.  That's correct, though, I need them.  (I can't cache the results as a string in the main record because an important piece of the display is how it compares to the schedule.)

Is there nothing to be done then?

Comment: Put the jobid's in a temp table that you can join with the child tables?

Comment: How are you measuring the performance, is it actually bad or is it ok and your wondering why the explain command is flagging it? Could you also post the ddl for relevant tables and the complex query you reference.

Comment: Recursive CTE (MySQL-8.0 / MariaDB-10.2)

Comment: @kevinnwhat Most of the time it's fine.  One screen has a lot more jobs on it, though, and is a problem.  Of course that's the screen the owner uses.  As for the explain command, it doesn't seem to show the database looking at anything beyond the data it needs to return--I think I'm hunting the impossible and have to attack this differently.